# How to simulate thousands of requests for the server

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-core, sql-server-2008, host

I want to simulate thousands of requests for the server host web api with .net core application in time not more than 5 seconds, and repeat this multible times at day to acheive 100 000 request at day once, and make this with another server which host javascript code and markup, but i don't have any idea about how doing this

Answer (score 1):

We recently used https://jmeter.apache.org/ for a project like this.